# Fully Differential OTA

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, transconductance, transconductance-amplifier

Based on the figure below, could you explain how a differential ota works ? how can I get the transfert function if I want to set a pole or a zero at the output with a differential resistor and a differential capacitor ? can I have drawing that explain  ? I'm a bit puzzle when it come to differential output [image]

Comment: [Fully differential OTA](http://tnt.etf.bg.ac.rs/~ms1aik/AIC-15_OTA_FD)

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka

Comment: @AnalogMan Ignoring push pull output variety, it's just a diff-amp (long-tailed pair type), a current source/sink tail, and a current mirror for both collector loads. If the mirror is perfectly matched, the long tailed pair is perfectly matched, and no difference at the inputs, the tail current is equally divided and the mirror itself is "happy." Any input difference immediately tries to change the split, one side getting more and the other less of the tail current. The mirror is no longer happy. So it tries to sink current at one output and source at the other and make things right, again.